# Term for the "Areas of Knowledge"

Tags: single-word-requests

Perhaps better said as the "fields of knowledge". I'm wondering whether there is a single word that describes fields of learning or knowledge. The word should work in the following sentences (where I've used *cognitum* and *cogniti* as fictitious placeholders for the singular and plural forms, respectively).

- "upon examination of the various *cogniti*, we can see common…"
- "Among the *cogniti* of classical education, I find Mathematics to be of great interest. As a *cognitum* it serves as the basis for all other *cogniti*; the universe itself is a consequence."

Comment: *Academic disciplines* gets it down to two words.

Comment: @200_success sure, I'll provide another example with made up words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be "disciplines."  Otherwise, you could go with what Harvard calls them: "concentrations."  Or other top tier schools: "specialties."

Answer (score 0):

I think the nearest you are going to get to what you want is ***philosophies*** - one of the OED definitions of *philosophy* being *a body of knowledge*.

The following is the first of nine separate OED broad senses (each with subdivisions) in which *philosophy* is defined:

> 1. Knowledge, learning, scholarship; **a body of knowledge**; spec. advanced knowledge or learning, to which the study of the seven
>      liberal arts was regarded as preliminary in medieval universities. Now
>      hist. exc. in degree titles, as Doctor, Master of Philosophy.

So I propose **Upon examination of the various *philosophies* we can see common...**

Answer (score 0):

I feel ***[expertise](https://www.google.com/search?q=expertise+meaning&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=17SVVsfRCpeVuAT7j6W4DQ)*** would be an appropriate term for this context

> expert skill or knowledge in a particular field.

[Google Definition]

**Use**: "Upon examination of the various ***expertise***, we can see common..."